# springmvc controller public or default protected

Tags: java, spring-mvc

what's different in public protected method?

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home(){
       "Hello World!"
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
       "Hello World!"
    }
```

Is it just mean public and protected in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference among 'public', 'default', 'protected', and 'private'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/difference-among-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: What do you mean by "default protected" and "public protected"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, since no one other than Spring and your unit tests should call these methods, making them public or protected doesn't change much.

I would leave them public because

- `protected` makes it look like the method is intended to be overridden, which it's not
- `public` makes it look like the method is intended to be called from the outside world, which it is (except it's being called through HTTP, and Spring is the one actually calling the method)
- if you need to make that method transactional, or otherwise proxied, then the method should be public